# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: desired capabilities error

Tags: java, android, selenium

After the attempt to run my tests I always get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{platformVersion=6.0, platformName=Android, deviceName=Xiomi}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

java-client 5.0.0 beta 9

Appium 1.6.5

selenium standalone 3.4.0

Using Android Studio

```
public class MyTest1 {

    AppiumDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Xiomi");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "6.0");
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void Test(){


    }

}
```

Please help! I can't understand what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've added next desired capabilities and exception stopped occurring:

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.package.app");        
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activities.App");
// Add real app package and activity instead of mine.
```